# Run 3d video on unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

One of my client want to run 3d video on Unity3d, I have two question

1. What is format of 3d videos.
2. Is this possible that we can run 3d video on iPhone and Android as well if it supported?
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant playing a video on a texture in a 3D scene, then Unity3D as a [MovieTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html) class you can use. Sadly, it requires a Pro license and doesn't work on iOs or Android :(

Answer (score 0):

add this code where you want to play a vedio:

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("MovieFileName.mp4",Color.black,FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput,FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
```

then put your movie file in Assets/StreamingAssets, movie file means:

.mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:
H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. Note that B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile. MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile).

details in: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html